# Get the record Id from the related list

Tags: lightning-aura-components

If we override the new button with custom component, then how we can get the record id of the record while clicking the New button from the related list?

I have used workspaceAPI to get the recodeId.

```
getCaseId : function(component) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var strVal = response.pageReference.state.ws;
        if(response.recordId){
             component.set('v.caseId', response.recordId);
        }else if(strVal){
            strVal = strVal.replace("/lightning/r/Case/", '');
            strVal = strVal.replace("/view", '');
            component.set('v.caseId', strVal);
        }
        //console.log('CASE ID:::' + component.get('v.caseId'));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

This is also working. But I am searching alternative solution.

Comment: Please provide some example code that you are using to allow people to better assist you.

Comment: I have added the code that I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I checked, accessing the parent Id from related list's button wasn't possible.

Here is the idea: [Get parentId when overriding standard actions with a lightning components](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E9hhQAC)

There were 2 workarounds:

1. [Wrap the aura component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256950/4726) in a VF page and use it for override.
2. [Parse the URL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/244382/4726) and get the Id.

Comment: Getting the Id from the URL is working

Comment: We can use workspaceapi to get the record id. May I know which one is best (workspaceapi or lightning:isUrlAddressable)

Comment: Whichever you find is easier to work with. :)